# How to check date range in datetimepicker jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, datetimepicker

i have used datetimepicker at https://github.com/xdan/datetimepicker, It's so cool, and i want to check date range of this in a week (7 days), i try with

```
               if ($("#FromDate").val() + 7 > $("#ToDate").val()) {
                   alert("Please choose a week");
                }
```

Example some case:

```
Fromdate: 27/10/2016 Todate: 31/10/2016 : OK
Fromdate: 27/10/2016 Todate: 2/11/2016 : OK
Fromdate: 27/10/2016 Todate: 3/11/2016 : show alert
```

But seem it not working.

Comment: Can you explain what isn't working?

Comment: Dear @James , i add descriptions , pls check again. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated the answer and it's working fine. Click here [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gvby1h9v/)

```
var fromDate = new Date($("#FromDate").val());
var sevenDate = new Date(fromDate.setDate(fromDate.getDate() + 7));
var toDate = new Date($("#ToDate").val());

if (sevenDate > toDate) {
    alert("Please choose a week");
}
```

Comment: still does not work? I have just checked the link included in my answer and it's fine. Let me know

Answer (score 0):

the way to do it is to convert date string into a date Object using `new Date()`

 
**But** there's a one problem if you use `'dd/mm/yy'` format it will not be valid as date when you convert
it into `new Date()` just rearrange it's format inyo a valid format I use format 'yy-mm-dd'

HTML

```
Start: <input id="from" type="text" /><br />
End: <input id="to" type="text" /><br />
<input id="thesubmit" type="button" value="Submit" />
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$(document).on('click', '#thesubmit', function() {
    var from = new $("#from").val().split('/');
  var to = new $("#to").val().split('/');
  from = new Date(from[2]+'-'+from[1]+'-'+from[0]);
  to = new Date(to[2]+'-'+to[1]+'-'+to[0]);

  if (new Date(from) == 'Invalid Date' || new Date(to) == 'Invalid Date') {
    return alert('Select a valid date');
  }

  var timeDiff = Math.abs(to.getTime() - from.getTime());
        var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24)); 
        if (diffDays >= 7) {
    alert('It is 1 week range');
  }
})
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/8w8v9/2203/)